# How to pass data to C# COM DLL from unmanaged application

Tags: c#, c++, dll, com

С# COM DLL Interface:

```
public interface IShowDialog
{
   void showMessage(byte[] array);
}
```

and call it in unmanaged C++ application:

```
SAFEARRAY *array;

array = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_BSTR, 0, 1);

long lidx = 0;

SafeArrayPutElement( array, &lidx, SysAllocString(L"test") );

hr = dlg->showMessage(array);
```

Result: `0x80131533 - COR_E_SAFEARRAYTYPEMISMATCH`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The COM interface needs to be called from native code with a `SAFEARRAY` whose contents are `VT_I1` instances.  You are providing instead `VT_BSTR` values and hence receiving the error.

You need to convert the string value into `VT_I1` values and put those into the array.

**EDIT**

The proper in C++ name is `VT_I1` and not `VT_BYTE`

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc235118(v=PROT.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc235118%28v=PROT.10%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 Agree that the safearray type passed in should match the declared type, but I'd say the IShowDialog::showMessage should accept a string (COM BSTR), not a byte[]